# Angular2 with ui-calendar,possible?

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, angular2-services, ui-calendar

I am new to angular2 world. I had a project developed using angularjs which used ui-calendar. Now as the requirement of the production changed we are moving to angular 2. Now my question is, is it possible to use ui-calendar with angular2. Because I couldn't find suitable materials for the same. If not is there any other alternatives (open source) that can be used in place of ui-calendar? Please help. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use `jquery` plugin in angular2 [but the people not recommend doing this]. Just install `jquery` from `npm` . Include the `jquery` and other js plugin you want to use in `angular.cli.json` file. And define global `jquery` variable as `declare var $:any` in the module you want.